# Is it quicker to compare against 0 vs compare against a value?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded

Is one of these loops quicker than the other?
I've always used #2 thinking it was quicker to compare against zero as opposed to comparing against a value in assembly since the CMP instruction would be simpler to execute but checking some ARM manuals I don't see anything to confirm this.  Does it depend on the instruction set and processor you're using? Is it ever true?

```
//#1
while(1)
    {
        static uint8_t counter = 0;
        counter++;
        if(counter == 4)
        {
            counter = 0;
            //do something
        }
    }


//#2
while(1)
    {
        static uint8_t counter = 4;
        counter--;
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            counter = 4;
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe yes. Maybe no. Depends on the architecture, compiler, optimization level and the context. Better write a code that is making sense to the reader and don't bother with micro-optimizations.

Comment: It could be quicker than comparing with a *variable*. For example if it does not matter in what sequence a loop is performed, but speed is crucial, I might make it count downwards from the variable (perhaps from `x - 1`) to save a memory access on each loop. The processor knows when the loop is complete from the processor flags after a decrement: no comparison is performed.

Comment: In assembly, yes, it is generally faster to compare with zero, because most processors have a specific instruction for that, while comparing with a value requires that value to be loaded from memory. But most modern compilers will notice that you aren't actually using the index and convert it for you.

Comment: This faster on arm as ‘subs’ vs ‘sub’ can be used.  I have seen compilers make this transformation at higher optimization levels.  It may even be that counter is redundant. How can an up count “make more sense” than a down count?  Either might make more sense depending on the problem space and I don’t see one as overly obtuse.

Comment: The decrement or sub instructions usually set a cpu flag (zeroflag) if the result is zero, so no explicit comparison is needed at all. Hence, the latter example is probably faster on many architectures.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell. Focusing on the release mode build, it largely depends on the context, and you aren't giving everything, especially the missing loop break condition makes it impossible to figure out.

Usually, if the number of iterations is an immediate value, the compiler will convert the loop construct to a fast counting down to zero one as long as there is no loop counter dependency inside the loop.

Anyway, on modern, superscalar architectures such as the Cortex-A series, a simple ALU instruction such as `cmp` will be well "hidden" and thus, won't cost an extra cycle most of the time.

What actually hurts the performance more is the `static` declaration of `counter` that automatically translates to memory RW. Avoid this if possible.

Further, if you simply want `do something` to run every fourth iteration, `if ((counter & 3) == 0)` could be the better solution that makes it possible to remove the counter resetting. And again, it all depends on the context (the length of "do something") which you didn't provide.

As a side note, local variables better be 32bit ones unless you have a good reason to declare them otherwise since anything less may translate to additional modulo related instructions such as `uxtb`, `and`, etc.

Counting down the loop counter to zero is a no brainer, but there are many more things to consider if you want the maximum performance.

Comment: You're right about missing context being important, didn't realize how relevant it was before reading some of the comments.  The loop never breaks because it isn't actually a loop, it's a timer interrupt at 88kHz and I'm trying initiate an SPI reading every interrupt call and setting a DAC output every 4th interrupt call(at 22kHz).  Figured this was irrelevant since the index of the loop is never used.  The architecture in question is an STM32L4 series